# String comparison in inside if else fails

Tags: string, if-statement, compare

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BeispielBundesländer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("How many states are there?");
        int states = scan.nextInt();
        String president = "Test Person";

        if (states == 9) {
            System.out.println("Good Job!");
            System.out.println("Now tell me the presidents name!");

            String presidentInput = scan.nextLine();

            if (presidentInput.equals(president)) {
            System.out.println("Well done!");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Fail!"); }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Fail!");
                }
    }
}
```

The string comparison in the second if '`presidentInput.equals(president)`' never works. I tried it with "`String presidentInput = scan.next();`" but the problem with that is that it only saves the first word e.g. "Test" in the variable presidentInput instead of "Test Person". So I tried `nextLine()` but with that doesn't even let me write anything, just jumps the fail.

Comment: May be that's coz your states is `!= 9`? I dont see any issue with code above, did you tried debugging?

Comment: Yes i tried to debug, if have absolutely no idea why this isn't working! It doesn't jump to fail after the first question when is use "scan.next()" instead of "scan.nextLine()" but as I said then it just saves the first word.
It also works perfectly fine when the first if asks also for a string, but first int question then string into it doesn't work.. do you know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class BeispielBundesländer {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("How many states are there?");
    int states = sc.nextInt();
    sc.nextLine();
    String president = "Test Person";
    if (states == 9) {
        System.out.println("Good Job!");
        System.out.println("Now tell me the presidents name!");
        String presidentInput = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println(presidentInput);
        if (presidentInput.equals(president)) {
            System.out.println("Well done!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Fail!");
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("Fail!");
    }
}
```

}

> The above code helps you.

```
int states = sc.nextInt();
```

> This reads the remainder of the line with the number on it (with nothing after the number I suspect)

Try placing a scanner.nextLine(); after each nextInt() if you intend to ignore the rest of the line.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was kind of desperate about this issue.